# Discord JS reaction err

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

could anyone explain to me why am I getting this error when I'm trying to get my role from a reaction: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: reaction.users.last is not a function? Thanks, I've attached the code too.

Code:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const config = require('./config.json');

client.on('ready', () => {
 console.log('Ready!');
});

client.on('message', async (message) => {
 if (message.content === 'l!verify') {
  const reactmessage = await message.channel.send(
   'Am intrebat 100 de Romani, vrei rolul de GUEST?'
  );
  await reactmessage.react('');

  const filter = (reaction, user) => reaction.emoji.name === '' && !user.bot;
  const collector = reactmessage.createReactionCollector(filter, {
   time: 15000,
  });
  collector.on('collect', async (reaction) => {
   const user = reaction.users.last();
   const guild = reaction.message.guild;
   const member = guild.member(user) || (await guild.fetchMember(user));
   member.addRole(config.roleid);
  });
 }
});
client.login(config.token);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`MessageReaction.users`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageReaction?scrollTo=users) returns a [`ReactionUserManager`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ReactionUserManager), not a `Collection`. Make sure to use the [`cache`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ReactionUserManager?scrollTo=cache) property.

```js
const user = reaction.users.cache.last();
```

Comment: Thanks! And by the way, if anyone needs this, there is another mistake I've done in my code.. "member.addRole(config.roleid);" should be "member.roles.add(config.roleid);"

Comment: If that's true, you're using v12, which means `guild.fetchMember()` should also be `guild.members.fetch()`